# Plottong several parametric surface in Maxima

Tags: graphing-functions, parametric, math-software, maxima-software

Is it possible to plot several parametric surfaces simultaneously using Maxima?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to plot several parametric surfaces with *Maxima*.

Let be $3N$ parametric functions:

$f_{i,w}(u,v), i =1..N, w =x,y,z.$

and $2N$ ranges:

$[t,t_{min,i},t_{max,i}], i =1..N, t=u,v$

For plotting just the $ith$ parametric surface (you know) you have to

$plot3d( [f_{i,x}(u,v), f_{i,y}(u,v), f_{i,z}(u,v)$],$[u,u_{min,i},u_{max,i}], [v,v_{min,i},v_{max,i}]$ ).

Well, for plotting the $N$ parametric surfaces, just enclose them into square brackets separated by commas:

$plot3d( [ [f_{1,x}(u,v), f_{1,y}(u,v), f_{1,z}(u,v)],[u,u_{min,1},u_{max,1}], [v,v_{min,1},v_{max,1}], [f_{2,x}(u,v), f_{2,y}(u,v), f_{2,z}(u,v)],[u,u_{min,2},u_{max,2}], [v,v_{min,2},v_{max,2}],...,[f_{N,x}(u,v), f_{N,y}(u,v), f_{N,z}(u,v)],[u,u_{min,N},u_{max,N}], [v,v_{min,N},v_{max,N}]]$ )